# SQL connection works in normal Java but not Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

The title kind of says the most of it but I want to connect to SQL using my Android app that I have in development so I made a sample set of code just to test the concept without using android and it worked.  When I tried to use it on Android it doesn't work (connection error) is there a permission  I need to request in my manifest?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: which database you are trying to connect

Comment: Have you android.permission.INTERNET permision?

Comment: I have connecting to mysql on host gator

Answer (score 1):

You can not establish JDBC connections to remote database in android either you should use SQLite DB on device or write socket based interface between your device and hosted machine or the most appropriate way of doing this is using REST webservices.